# load function not working fine on chrome

Tags: jquery, load

Below is the code, the issue is #smsregid.val is changing in Firefox but not in Chrome, any suggestions why

```
function subSmsForm() {
    $.post('?action=smsregistration-save', $('#smsform').serialize(),

   function(data) {
            $('#mess').html(data.message);
            $('#mess').show();
            $('#signup').hide();
            $('#verify').show();
            $('#verify').load('?action=verification');
            alert(data.smsregid);
            $('#smsregid').val(data.smsregid);
        }, "json");
}
```

Comment: can u see in alert what is the value for data.smsregid in chrome

Comment: value is coming what i need but the #smsregid is not updating

Comment: can u show complete code

Comment: ok, edited for complete code

Comment: #smsregid is inside verify.load page

Answer (score 0):

try this once

```
 $('#smsregid').prop('value', data.smsregid);
```

Comment: I would say value is a prop not a attr - based on no markup its all just a guess however.

Comment: No, it doesn't, I forgot to mention that #smsregid is coming through .load()

Comment: @PSR are you checking on firefox, because in firefox it is working fine but not on chrome

Comment: it seems that it is bug with chrome, many users facing same issues

Comment: i am also thinking like that